# Merge ranges in one column

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following script copying a range "F30:F37", "G30:G37" from Sheet 1. I am trying to select both ranges into Sheet2 starting with ROW G101. However, only Sheet 1 "G30:G37" data copies into Sheet 2, ROW G101. What could be the issue, would you be able to simplify my data pull? Listed below, Macro:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim SHEET2 As Worksheet


Set Results = Sheets("SHEET2")
LastRow = Results.Cells(Results.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row


Range("F30:F37").Copy
Results.Range("G" & LastRow + 101).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("G30:G37").Copy
Results.Range("G" & LastRow + 101).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.DataEntryMode = False
End Sub
```

This is how column with rows display, please note, row G has no header:
[image]

This would be my result:

[My result would look like the second image, sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICWML.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, Results is a variable that should be in your `Dim` statement, not `"Sheet2"`.  Secondly, you are pasting over the first paste.  If you want row 101 for the first, paste in row 101.  Then find the last row and paste the info below.  And lastly, you want `Application.CutCopyMode` to take you out of the copy/paste.

```
Sub CopyData()

     Dim LastRow As Long
     Dim Results As Worksheet

     Set Results = Sheets("SHEET2")



     Range("F30:F37").Copy
     Results.Range("G101").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     LastRow = Results.Cells(Results.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
     Range("G30:G37").Copy
     Results.Range("G" & LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


     Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey there, after I ran your script I get the following error:  Run time error 438, Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Script also deletes "% CHANGE" header.

Comment: You can change G101 to G102 if the header is 101.  I assume you got the error on `Application.CutCopyMode`.  There was a typo and I had Code instead of Mode.